# Retrieve keys Set from pandas Series of dict values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a pandas `Series` of `dict` values with `str` keys:

```
Series
------
{'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
{'b': 3, 'd': 5}
{'d': 7, 'e': 7}
```

**How can the Series be scanned to retrieve a set of the dictionary keys?** The resulting output would be a plain python set:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flattening and convert to sets:

```
a = set([y for x in s for y in x])
print (a)
{'e', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'b'}
```

Or use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from  itertools import chain

a = set(chain.from_iterable(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
s = pd.Series(...)
a = set(list(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())))
# {'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```